# Failed to find Premain-Class manifest attribute ... spock-mockable

Tags: java, groovy, jvm, spock

I am trying to stub the final class java.net.UR in my spock testL. Based on the answer here: [How to stub a java final static method or class in Spock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75691233/how-to-stub-a-java-final-static-method-or-class-in-spock) I'm attempting to use [spock-mockable](https://github.com/joke/spock-mockable).

I have modified my build.gradle as follows:

```
testImplementation (
        'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.1',
        'org.spockframework:spock-core:2.4-M1-groovy-4.0',
        'io.github.joke:spock-mockable:3d2e39a',
        'cglib:cglib-nodep:3.3.0'
)

...

// to load the agent even earlier add it as a JVM argument
tasks.withType(Test) {
    jvmArgs += ["-javaagent:${classpath.find { it.name.contains('spock-mockable') }.absolutePath}"]
}
```

From reading the readme file, it looks like I can now just run my test, but when I try it, I get the following error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Failed to find Premain-Class manifest attribute in /home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.github.joke/spock-mockable/3d2e39a/d3a086b4c82c8290a2013ebd5a6b697f959918bf/spock-mockable-3d2e39a.jar
agent library failed to init: instrument
```

I'm not exactly sure what a javaagent is and tried to find some reading on it, but found several examples with no explanation. I can kind of guess.

At any rate, the spock-mockable shows up in my external libraries. (From IntelliJ where I'm running this test.)

[image]

Looking for what to do next.

Comment: @JimGarrison Not sure what file you mean. I searched for javaagent and spock-mockable

Comment: @JimGarrison I used qwant before. Tried google at your request and still am not finding anything relevant to me. The most likely one is a space between the key and value, but I'm not coding that. The PreMain class is defined by the package I'm bringing in. Not sure how this helps.

Comment: Hello. I would appreciate some feedback. I spent some time and effort on writing a comprehensive answer, which I think is correct and should solve your problem. Please be so kind as to accept & upvote, unless you have any follow-up questions.

Answer (score 1):

Spock Mockable version 3d2e39a is old (May 2022), not a recent version as the leading "3" implies. According to both the GitHub site and MvnRepository.com, the latest release is 2.3.1.

[image: mvnrepository.com screenshot for Spock Mockable]

If you inspect the JAR of version 3d2e39a, you will find an empty *META-INF/MANIFEST.MF* file, which is the root cause for your error message. There really is no [`Premain-Class` entry](https://www.baeldung.com/java-instrumentation#create-agent-manifest-file) there, which would be necessary to run the JAR as a Java agent. But 2.3.1 has the correct manifest entries.